# find a tree, given the data on its leaves

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory

let there be an undirected  tree `T`, and let there be: `T.leaves` - all the leaves (each v such that `d(v) = 1`). we know: `|T.leaves|` and the `distance between u and v for each u,v in T.leaves`.

**in other words**: we have an undirected tree, and we know how many leaves it has, and the distance between every 2 leaves.

we need to find `how many inside vertices (d(v)>1) are in the tree`.

note: building the complete tree is impossible because if we have only 2 leaves but the distance between them is 2^30, it will take too long...

I tried to start from the shortest distance and count how many vertices are between them, and then adding the vertex closest to them, but for this I need some formula f(leaves_counted,next_leaf) but I could not manage to find that f...

any ideas?

Comment: You can actually build this tree. Just keep non-branching paths compressed (store one edge + its length) and add internal nodes as necessary. So two nodes 2^31 apart is just 2 nodes plus one physical edge labeled 2^31. Not sure if you actually *need to*, but you can.

Comment: @Rafal: but when you are trying to add another vertex, you will need to check all possibilities (unless I miss something), and you will need to iterate over this distance.

Comment: gr: Not necessarily, you can solve the equations just as if the distances were floats.

Comment: @Rafal: care to elaborate?If you have a tree (not simple as the one discussed above, but with a large number of leaves) - how do you choose where to add the new vertex without iterating the distances between two leaves?

Comment: gr: Continued in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continued from discussion in comments. This is how to check a particular (compressed) edge to see if you can attach the new vertex `n` somewhere in the middle of it, without iterating over the distances.

[image: tree]

Ok, so you need to find three numbers: `l` (the distance of the attach point from the left node of the edge in question), `x` (the distance of the new node from the attach point) and `r` (symmetrical to `l`.)

Obviously, for every node `y` in set `L` (the left part of the tree), its distance to `A` must differ from its distance to `n` by the same number (lets call it `dl` which must be equal `l` + `x`). If this is not the case, there is no solution for this particular edge. Same goes for nodes in `R`, with `dr` and `r` + `x` respectively.

If the above holds, then you have three equations:

`l + x = dl`

`r + x = dr`

`r+l = dist(A,B)`

Three equations, three numbers. If this has a solution then you have found the right edge.

At worst you need to iterate the above for every edge, but I think it can be optimized - the distance check on `L` and `R` might exclude one of the parts of the tree from further search. It might also be possible to somehow get the number of nodes without even constructing the tree.

Comment: I'll try to implement it today/tomorrow and come back for feedback about this answer. thanks!

Comment: @amit gr: Note that there's probably room for optimization. This was just to show a useful idea rather than the complete optimal algorithm.

Comment: worked perfectly, but a few comments if anyone tries it in the future: dist(A,B) = r+l-1 (since there is a single vertex which is counted twice) and, every step we need to add min{x} for every two vertices (A,B) already in the tree. the problem is solved this way in O(n^3), I am sure an optimization can be done to find min{x} in less then O(n^2) [with appropriate add order of each vertex].

Comment: optimization: we do no need to iterate over all possible tuples (v1,v2), we can iterate over all tuples (root,v) where root is constant, we do this for every vertex, and we get O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

if your binary tree has L leaves then it has L-1 internal vertices regardless of the shape of the tree.

You can easily prove this: start with the tree with only one node (root) node. Then take any leaf, and add two descendants to it, converting the leaf into an internal vertex and adding to leaves. This removes one leaf (the old node), and adds one internal node and two leaves, i.e. net is +1 internal node and +1 leaf. Because you start with one leaf and 0 internal nodes, you have always |leaves| = |internal nodes|+1 --- any tree shape can be produced by this process.

Here examples of all the two shapes of trees with 4 leaves (save for trivial left-right symmetries):

```
    o        o
   o L      o o
  o L     L L L L
 L L
```

The number of internal vertices is always 3.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a binary tree.